# passing by reference in C++ 11 threads; changes are localized

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, stdthread

I am trying to fasten some processing of my `opencv` code using C++ 11 threads.

In a meanwhile I am using vector for sharing data

Please consider a following piece of code:

```
start_t = cv::getTickCount();
std::vector <std::thread>   tMSE_Calc(nComparisons);
std::vector<float> sum;
sum.resize(nComparisons);

for(int i = 0 ; i < nComparisons ; ++i)
{
    tMSE_Calc[i] = std::thread(FindMSE_Fast, vector1, vector2, sum, i);
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < nComparisons ; ++i)
{
    tMSE_Calc[i].join();
}
end_t = cv::getTickCount();
logfile << "Actual Comparison Took " << (end_t - start_t) * freq * 1000 << " milliseconds"<< std::endl;

for(int i = 0 ; i < nComparisons ; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Sum[" << i << "] = " << sum[i] << std::endl;
}
```

And I have a thread function:

```
void FindMSE_Fast(cv::Mat& m1, cv::Mat& m2, std::vector<float>& sumVec, int idx)
{
    cv::Mat s;
    cv::absdiff(m1, m2, s);
    s = s.mul(s);
    cv::Scalar sum = cv::sum(s);
    sumVec[idx] = cv::sqrt(sum[0]);
    std::cout << "Difference is: " << cv::sqrt(sum[0]) << "index is: " << sumVec[idx] << std::endl;

    //std::cout << "Difference is: " << cv::sqrt(sum[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

It seems so obvious to me that vector sum should be modified at the end of thread calls, but when I print it in main thread later, all of its contents are zero.

Is there something different that we need to do with function parameters in order to pass by reference?

Comment: There's a bunch of dups for this. Basically, `std::thread`'s constructor makes a copy of the arguments, essentially passing by value. Use a lambda capturing by reference or use `std::ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound function arguments are copied and are not passed by reference. This behavior is the same, e.g., with `std::bind()`. The arguments are passed as deduced `T&&` to the constructor but that's only used to initialize some held values.

If you don't want the arguments to be copied, you'd pass a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` instead, e.g., using

```
std::thread(FindMSE_Fast, vector1, vector2, std::ref(sum), i)
```

while pass `sum` by reference. Since `std::reference_wrapper<T>` has a conversion operator to `T&` your function will be called appropriately.